# Line brake in jsp datagrid column tag

Tags: jsp, datagrid, jstl

Let see the following code

```
  <column width="150">
     <header value="Name" hAlign="center" styleClass="header"/>
     <item   value="${employee.firstName} ${employee.lastName}" hAlign="left"       styleClass="item"/>
        </column>
```

It will print result in same line,But I need a line break between the result of employee.firstName and
employee.lastName.

How can I achieve it.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tag in HTML and JSP for break the line

> `<br>`

or

> `</br>`

tag try this ..use it where you wanna break line i.e. at the end of the line, and want o/p in next line hope it'll work for you. and u can check with **\n** for next line.

Comment: i tried like this <item   value="${employee.firstName} <br> ${employee.lastName}" hAlign="left"       styleClass="item"/>. But it is giving error